# Writing Text Effect with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am use this code for Writing Text Effect:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function changeText(cont1, cont2, speed) {
            var Otext = cont1.text();
            var Ocontent = Otext.split("");
            var i = 0;
            function show() {
                if (i < Ocontent.length) {
                    cont2.append(Ocontent[i]);
                    i = i + 1;
                };
            };
            var Otimer = setInterval(show, speed);
        };
        $(document).ready(function () {
            changeText($("#TypeEffect p"), $(".p2"), 150);
        });
    });
</script>
```

but its not working for multiline, I use this code:

```
 changeText($("#TypeEffect p, #TypeEffect br"), $(".p2"), 150);
```

so, its not working.

please help me for Writing Text Effect in multi line.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zj6pD/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: its not wroking for multi line: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zj6pD/1/ with: <p>Some content<br />Some content</p>

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zj6pD/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function changeText(cont1, cont2, speed) {
        var contents = $(cont1).contents().map(function () {
            if (this.nodeType == 3) {
                if ($.trim(this.nodeValue).length) {
                    return this.nodeValue.split("")
                }
            } else {
                return $(this).clone().get();
            }
        }).get();
        var i = 0;

        function show() {
            if (i < contents.length) {
                cont2.append(contents[i]);
                i = i + 1;
            } else {
                clearInterval(Otimer)
            }
        };
        var Otimer = setInterval(show, speed);
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        changeText($("#TypeEffect p"), $(".p2"), 150);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zj6pD/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("[class*=autoWrite]").each(function(e){
    autoWriteText($(this));
   })
 
 function autoWriteText(elm){
  var clas = elm.attr("class");
  clas = clas.split("-");
  var speed = clas[1];
  var delay = clas[2];
  var txt = elm.html();
  elm.html("");
  setTimeout(function(){
   elm.fadeIn("fast");
   txt = txt.split("");
   var txtI = 0;
   var html = "";
   var intrvl = setInterval(function(){
    html = html + txt[txtI] ;
    elm.html(html  + "_");
    txtI = txtI + 1;
    if(txtI == txt.length){
     clearInterval(intrvl);
    }

   },speed);
  },delay)
 }
```

```css
.autoWriteText{
   display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="autoWrite-10-0" >This element will write a <b>letter every 10 milliseconds</b> in this box, with a <b>delay of 0 milliseconds</b>.</h5>
<hr>
 <h5 class="autoWrite-50-1000" >This element will write a <b>letter every 50 milliseconds</b> in this box, with a <b>delay of 1 second</b>.</h5>
<hr>
 <h5 class="autoWrite-200-3000" >This element will write a <b>letter every 200 milliseconds</b> in this box, with a <b>delay of 3 second</b>.</h5>
<hr>
 <h5 class="autoWrite-500-5000" >This element will write a <b>letter every 500 milliseconds</b> in this box, with a <b>delay of 5 second</b>.</h5>
<hr>
```